# Convergence in $L^1$ and boundedness in $L^{\infty}$ imply strong convergence in $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real functions and $f\in L^1\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that
\begin{align}
f_n\to f \text{ in } L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ and }  f_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} f \text{  in } L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).
\end{align}
The weak$^{*}$ convergence immediately implies that $f_n{\rightharpoonup}f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $1<p<\infty$. Indeed the weak$^{*}$ convergence implies
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n \varphi dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f \varphi dx
\end{align}
for any $\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Hence we have weak convergence in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since $f\in L^1\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Is it true that we even get strong convergence?

Comment: $|f_n-f|^{p} \leq |f_n-f| \|f_n-f\|_{\infty}^{p-1}$.

Comment: weak convergence in $L^p$ means that $\int f_n\varphi \to \int f\varphi $ for all $\varphi \in L^q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$. So, no reason for $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ weakly.

Comment: @Surb If it holds for $\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}$ it also holds for all $\varphi\in L^q$. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks!

Comment: no it's not true, $L^q$ is a much bigger space than $\mathcal C_0^\infty $.

Comment: $C_0^{\infty}$ denote the test functions and then we can argue by density